# Issue using the django usercreationform, not rendering form in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

im making a signup page in a django project using the UserCreationForm but when rendering my html i only see the submit button

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm
    return(render(request, 'register.html', {form: form}))
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="button">
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the form as key of the context, you should use `'form'`. Furthermore it is *not* a good idea to pass a reference to the class, you should create an *instance* of the form in the view, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    #            use 'form' instead of form  ↓    ↓
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

If you had used a form *object*, instead of a reference to the class, it would have raised an error that a `Form` is not hashable. But since you used a reference to the form class, there was no error, and thus this remained undetected.

Comment: thank you for your reply, although you have solved part of my issue another has arisen. Although the form displays when i dont extend the base HTML, it doesnt display when i do. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would advise to ask a new question. Define a *minimal working example* so share the relevant parts of the view, template, base template, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the django views function..Use below code instead..
you should pass it as a string variable {'form' :form}

```
return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```